# error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 0

Tags: git

I'm attempting to push to a repository on an in-house Bonobo git server.

I regularly push to 2 other repositories on the same server with no issue.

I have just created a new repository with the same permissions as the existing ones, but for a new project. I cloned it onto my desktop (Windows 7, using the latest Git and TortoiseGit).

Cloning and fetching seems fine (as it should, it's empty), but pushing gets this far before hanging indefinitely (right now it's been pushing since yesterday morning):

```
git.exe push --force --progress  "com19" master:master
Counting objects: 8199
Counting objects: 11497, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (11083/11083)
Writing objects: 100% (11497/11497), 74.46 MiB | 1.29 MiB/s
Writing objects: 100% (11497/11497), 74.86 MiB | 1.31 MiB/s, done.
Total 11497 (delta 1239), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

The last time I tried to do this, I received this error message after 8+ hours of hanging:

```
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 0
Everything up-to-date

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1)
```

I have seen this error code posted here before, but every post about it seems to have an accepted answer of `git config --global http.postBuffer 2M`. I have used this command several times to no avail, currently the postbuffer is 500M.

The repository has a url prefix of `http` and does not use SSL, but this is the case for all repositories on this server that I have no issues pushing to.

The problem persists whether I use the `-u` param or not.

Answer (score 0):

Git uses libcurl to do its HTTP pushing and fetching, and error 56 is `CURLE_RECV_ERROR`. This means that Git encountered an error when attempting to receive data from the network. For example, the connection may have been closed unexpectedly.

Usually this means that there's some sort of network problem. That could be a physical network problem, or a firewall, proxy, or filter problem. In some cases, if you have anti-virus installed, it could be intercepting your network connections and causing this as well.

You should try to thoroughly investigate the cause of network issues both local and external, including trying to disable your anti-virus if you have one.

Comment: Is there any reason why a firewall or network issue would only affect one repository and not the other two when all three are on the same server and being pushed to from the same machine?

Comment: You could have one repository which is larger or compresses differently, leading to different traffic patterns. You could have a data-dependent network problem where certain patterns trigger a buggy network card, or certain data being sent triggers a filtering proxy or an anti-virus heuristic. Overall, the error means the connection is being dropped, so you'd want to look for reasons why that is.